# JAXB: how to get value in wrapped type?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "toplist")
class toplist {

    private String description;

    private List<Item> items= new ArrayList<Item>();

    @XmlElement(name = "description")
    public String getDescription() {...}
    public String setDescription() {...}

    @XmlElement(name = "item")
    @XmlElementWrapper(name = "items")
    public List<ChartResultItem> getToplistEntries() {...}
}

class Item {
    private String attr1;
    private String attr2;
    private String attr3;

    // getter and setter with
    //     @XmlAttribute(name = "atter1"), @XmlAttribute(name = "atter2") and etc
}
```

AND xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<toplist>
    <description>This is description.</description>
    <items>
        <item attr1="" attr2="" attr3="">value1</item>
        <item attr1="" attr2="" attr3="">value2</item>
        <item attr1="" attr2="" attr3="">value3</item>
        ...
    </items>
</toplist>
```

How can I get value1, value2, value3 and etc in the Item class (by jaxb) ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Jom's answer is correct (+1).  Here's an example to further explain:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Item {
    @XmlValue
    protected String value;

    @XmlAttribute
    protected String attr1;

    @XmlAttribute
    protected String attr2;

    @XmlAttribute
    protected String attr3;
}
```

Comment: If I use XmlValue annotation then get exception

com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 2 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions
If a class has @XmlElement property, it cannot have @XmlValue property.

Comment: Yes that makes sense.  Does your Item tag contain text as well as sub-elements?  The XmlValue and XmlAttribute should be on the Item class, not the toplist class.

Comment: Not as sub-elements this is xml   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<toplist>
    <description>This is description.</description>
    <items>
        <item attr1="" attr2="" attr3="">value1</item>
        <item attr1="" attr2="" attr3="">value2</item>
        <item attr1="" attr2="" attr3="">value3</item>
        ...
    </items>
</toplist>

Comment: Sorry i don't understand your last comment.  Please post your entire Item class so we can see where you're getting that error from.

Comment: Please see xml in my question above. And XmlValue and XmlAttribute contains in the Item class.

Comment: I have seen the XML... what i want to see is the Item class.  I can't see any @XmlElement annotations in it so i can't see why you're getting that error

Comment: I tried so `class Item {
    private String attr1;
    private String attr2;
    private String attr3;

 private Stirng value;

    @XmlAttribute(name = "atter1")
 public String getAttr1() {...}

 @XmlAttribute(name = "atter2")
 public String getAttr1() {...}

 @XmlAttribute(name = "atter3")
 public String getAttr1() {...}

 @XmlValue
 public String getValue() {...}
}`

and get exception com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 2 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions If a class has @XmlElement property, it cannot have @XmlValue property.

Comment: Ok, but your class Item does not have an XmlElement or an XmlValue therefore it cannot be this class that is causing the problem - the error must be coming from somewhere else.

Comment: If you are going to annotate the fields you should also use the class level annotation: @XmlAcessorType(XmlAcessType.FIELD).  This will solve the issue you are seeing.

Comment: alpian could you write correct Item class (with XmlElement, XmlAttribute and XmlValue) please ?

Answer (score 6):

You are probably looking for the [XmlValue](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlValue.html) annotation.